# How to arrange different html (<p>,<h>) using if else in AngularJS (ngIf)

Tags: angularjs

I want to edit HTML&CSS code to arrange it differently on the page depending if a condition is met or not using AngularJS (ng commands)

I have thisYear=true or false

If thisYear is true I want the labels and input HTML tags from the page to be arrange in a certain way using inLine css if the year is false I want to arrange it in a different way.

How can I set up an if/else statement in AngularJS  (ngIf) and edit the html and CSS inLine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add something like this in your view:

```
<div ng-if="thisYear">
    <!-- Displays stuff when thisYear is true -->
</div>
<div ng-if="!thisYear">
    <!-- Displays stuff when thisYear is false -->
</div>
```

Also, add the css classes to particular div for styling.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though there are multiple things that you may be asking for. I think you could benefit from using the ng-style and ng-class directives as well as the ng-if directive.

Using ng-if will allow you to load a div into the DOM based upon whether or not the boolean value is true or false. With this, you can easily arrange your labels in whatever position you'd like.

```
<div ng-if="inputTrue">
    <!-- your input/labels go here and will be loaded into the DOM -->
</div>
 <div ng-if="!inputTrue">
    <!-- this input will not be loaded into the DOM -->
</div>
```

In addition to this, you can also take advantage of the ng-class and ng-style directives. Using ng-class will allow you to add a class to the div based on a condition that evaluates to true or false. The same thing goes for the ng-style directive.

It would follow something along the lines of ng-class="{'className':inputTrue}".

Comment: Thx works fine. I had some problems finding the right syntax! :D